# Convert an object datatype column with format mm:ss to a time format pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has an column that has an object datatype with the format mm:ss.  I want to convert that column to a time format so that I could turn the time into seconds instead of mm:ss.  However, I have not been able to convert the column into a time format.

Example of my data:

```
time
33:22
24:56
30:15
26:57
```

I have tried:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
```

How do I convert this object data type column to a time format?  And ultimately to total seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add '00:' to the beginning.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['time'])
df['total seconds'] = df['time'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: I didn't know you could add the zeros like that!!!  Thank you so much!  That worked perfectly!